# Formato campo Time en Django template

Tags: python, django

Hola a todos estoy teniendo problemas al momento de presentar un campo time en un template Django.

Model:

```
 hora_inicial = models.TimeField(blank=True)
 hora_final = models.TimeField(blank=True)
```

Template:

```
{{form.hora_inicial|time:"H:i"}}
{{form.hora_final|time:"H:i"}}
```

Asi se guarda en las base de datos postgresql:

```
hora_inicial: 00:00:00
hora_final : 23:59:00
```

Asi presenta en template:

```
hora_inicial: media noche
hora_ginal : 1 pm.
```

Deseo se presente tal como se guarda en la base de datos. Espero me puedan ayudar.
Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Para dar el formato que quieres, que seria `horas:minutos:segundos`, seria de la siguiente manera:

```
{{ form.hora_inicial|time:"H:i:s" }} # 00:00:00
{{ form.hora_final|time:"H:i:s" }} # 23:59:00
```

`H` da un formato de 24 horas (`h` daría un formato de 12 horas), `i` de minutos y `s` de segundos, con ceros a la izquierda.

También podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
{{ form.hora_inicial|time:"H\h:i\m:s\s" }}
```

Que daría como resultado:

```
23h:59m:00s
```

Puedes dar muchos mas formatos, como `u` de microsegundos, etc. Para mas información visita la [documentación de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date).